# BigInteger Operations internally

Tags: java, large-data

`BigInteger` is used for operations on integer that actually overflow the int range (2 to the power 32),  like computing factorial of 100 etc.

How does actually `BigInteger` store the intermediate values or the final value?

Comment: http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value is stored as an int array

```
int[] mag;
```

Use the source Luke :)

[grepcode__openjdk_math_BigInteger](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java)